# How to extract cookie from Jmeter (set-cookie)

Tags: jmeter

My Jmeter response is like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
server: nginx/1.21.0
date: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 06:40:00 GMT
content-type: application/json
transfer-encoding: chunked
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.16
expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, private, post-check=0, pre-check=0
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-security-policy: frame-ancestors 'self';
set-cookie: SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519=MOeap41l9fMul8f4I-CYcSou65ACg2yNqIFEcOw4xrA; path=/;`
```

I need to extract the value of **set-cookie: SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519**

CookieManager.save.cookies=true is added into user.properties file

I tried using: Regular Expression Extractor as bellow:

[image]

But, seems like my exepression is not working.

1. How to extrack this cookie?
2. Once extracted, should I use as
   ${TOKEN} or ${COOKIE_TOKEN}?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)'s built-in mechanism for storing the cookies you can access it as:

```
${COOKIE_SSESS8b04132f4690dc8ceb7837d5134a5519}
```

If you want to use [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - you need to use

```
${TOKEN}
```

but you will need to switch the "Field to check" to **Response Headers**